# make specific commands guild discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i wanna make this welcome command work on my specific server,i have 2 server on same bot.if i invite member to server 2 the command will error because i just set id to server 1.how to put the command just work on my server 1?

```
const rules = '737279140784242708' // rules and info
const leave = '743838756875796502' //leave message
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    if (member.guild.id = '580588806571294720') {

        const message = `Hello <@${member.id}>, welcome to **${member.guild.name}**!,Jangan lupa check ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(rules)} yaa`

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.send(message)
    }
})

bot.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
    if (member.guild.id = '580588806571294720') {

        const message = `<@${member.id}>, telah pergi`

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(leave)
        channel.send(message)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to check if the guild that was joined is server 1, and not server 2.

```
if (member.guild.id === the_id_of_server_1) {
    //Do all the messaging stuff
}
```

This way, it will only try to do all of those things if the event was called in server 1, and won't throw any errors.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined,i just edit my code please check that correct or not,thanks

Comment: Your comparison is wrong, you only used 1 equals sign while it should be 3 (which should also error in your IDE). That's why the `if` does nothing, and it tries to fetch that channel from server2, which doesn't have it, so it returns null, which causes that error.